# Every photo has a .xmp file next to it in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I do a lot of photography. I have noticed that every one of my photo's now has a .xmp file next to the photo with the same name. These .xmp files are taking up a lot of space. Is there a way to turn off these files from forming in Ubuntu?
Is it safe to erase these files as I have several thousand of them?

Comment: From where are you looking photos, is it from an SD card?

Comment: no they are in my "Pictures" folder in Ubuntu